# Search for unicode in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, unicode

In a project's code there's this part:

```
$companies = $db->fetchAll("SELECT id FROM companies where contact_person like '%num%\"". $num. "\"%'");
```

`contact_person` is a json string in postgres db. For example, $num = 'ЦВ123456' (ЦВ - cyrillic symbols). But it also be without cyrillic symbols. I use json_encode on $num to get `\u041c\u04203705516`, but in postgres you need to escape slashes so it should be `\\u041c\\u04203705516` to get a hit. So what should I do? Do I need to change the query or do I add slashes to $num ?

Full json:

```
{"informationPersonInfo":{"nameInfo":{"lastname":"\u0424\u0430\u043c\u0438\u043b\u0438\u044f","firstname":"\u0418\u043c\u044f","middlename":""},"inn":"","position":"\u0420\u0443\u043a\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u043d\u0430\u043f","identityDocInfo":{"passportForeignInfo":{"number":"\u0426\u0412123456","issuedBy":"\u0422\u0415\u0421\u0422","issueDate":"27.07.2019","validityDate":"","issuingStateInfo":{"countryCode":"123421"}}}}}
```

Trying to select for "ЦВ123456"

Comment: Try to add a complete (example) JSON string in your question, together with the value that you a re trying to select.

Comment: @Luuk added the full json

Answer (score 0):

This will select `number`:

```
WITH cte as (
   SELECT '{"informationPersonInfo":{"nameInfo":{"lastname":"\u0424\u0430\u043c\u0438\u043b\u0438\u044f","firstname":"\u0418\u043c\u044f","middlename":""},"inn":"","position":"\u0420\u0443\u043a\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u043d\u0430\u043f","identityDocInfo":{"passportForeignInfo":{"number":"\u0426\u0412123456","issuedBy":"\u0422\u0415\u0421\u0422","issueDate":"27.07.2019","validityDate":"","issuingStateInfo":{"countryCode":"123421"}}}}}' as json
)
SELECT json::JSON#>'{ informationPersonInfo, identityDocInfo, passportForeignInfo, number }' as number 
FROM cte;
```

output:

| number |
| --- |
| "\u0426\u0412123456" |

For more info see: [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html)

EDIT: When you do not know the exact path to `number`, you can use this:

```
with recursive cte1 as (
 select 0 as x, '{"informationPersonInfo":{"nameInfo":{"lastname":"\u0424\u0430\u043c\u0438\u043b\u0438\u044f","firstname":"\u0418\u043c\u044f","middlename":""},"inn":"","position":"\u0420\u0443\u043a\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u043d\u0430\u043f","identityDocInfo":{"passportForeignInfo":{"number":"\u0426\u0412123456","issuedBy":"\u0422\u0415\u0421\u0422","issueDate":"27.07.2019","validityDate":"","issuingStateInfo":{"countryCode":"123421"}}}}}'::json as j
),
cte2 as (
   select x, key, value, json_typeof(value) as "type"
   from cte1
   cross join json_each(cte1.j) j2
   
   union all
   
   select x+1, j22.key, j22.value, json_typeof(j22.value)
   from cte2 
   cross join json_each(cte2.value::json) j22
   where cte2.type = 'object'
   )
select * 
from cte2
where key = 'number';
```

This will output:

| x | key | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | number | "\u0426\u0412123456" | string |

Comment: I can't use it, because keys can be different in json. There may be no 'passportForeignInfo'

Comment: edited my answer, an added an approach when you do not know the exact path to `number`.